# Getting error : "react-dom.production.min.js:216 TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" while deploying react app on github pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, github-pages

I am trying to deploy my react application and its not rendering the page properly, It is throwing the below error : react-dom.production.min.js:216 TypeError: Object(...) is not a function.

I have linked the screenshot of the error and the file name along with my github link of the repo.[![

```js
Expense.js

import { useState } from "react";
import "../css/Expenses.css";
import Card from "./Card";
import ExpenseItem from "./ExpenseItem";
import Filter from "./Filter";

function Expenses(props){
    let data = props.data;
    let [year,changeYear] = useState("2021");

    let data2 = data.filter(function(item){
      return(new Date(item.dates).getFullYear().toString() === year);
    })
    

    let setFilter = function(yearValue){
      changeYear(yearValue);
    }


    return(
     <Card className = "card">
     <div className="filter-section">
       <h3>Filter By Year</h3>
       <Filter sendData={setFilter} yearVal = {year} className='year-filter-card'/>
     </div>
     <div className="expense-wrap">
          {data2.length?
            data2.map(function(expItem) {
             return <ExpenseItem key={Math.random()*100000} item= {expItem} deleteMe={props.deleteMe}/>  
          }):
          <h2 className="nodata">No Expense Data</h2> 
    }
    </div>
     </Card>
    );
    
}

export default Expenses;
```

link to my repo: https://github.com/AbhishekTomr/money-tracker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved now had to use this line:

```
import React,{ useState } from "react";
```